# When iterating through a set of numbers, will time increase at a constant exponential rate

Tags: math, time, cpu

Hello good people of stackoverflow, this is a conceptual question and could possibly belong in math.stackexchange.com, however since this relates to the processing speed of a CPU, I put it in here.

Anyways, my question is pretty simple. I have to calculate the sum of the cubes of 3 numbers in a range of numbers. That sounds confusing to me, so let me give an example.

I have a range of numbers, (0, 100), and a list of each numbers cube. I have to calculate each and every combination of 3 numbers in this set. For example, 0 + 0 + 0, 1 + 0 + 0, ... 98^3 + 99^3 + 100^3. That may make sense, I'm not sure if I explained it well enough.

So anyways, after all the sets are computed and checked against a list of numbers to see if the sum matches with any of those, the program moves on to the next set, (100, 200). This set needs to compute everything from 100-200 + 0-200 + 0-200. Than (200, 300) will need to do 200 - 300 + 0 - 300 + 0 - 300 and so on.

So, my question is, depending on the numbers given to a CPU to add, will the time taken increase due to size? And, will the time it takes for each set exponentially increase at a predictable rate or will it be exponential, however not constant.

Comment: Note that checking "against a list of numbers to see if the sum matches with any of those" is not a free operation.  Depending upon the data structure used to store this set, this check could have runtime ranging from O(1) to O(n) (where n is the number of distinct sums that are being stored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time to add two numbers is logarithmic with the magnitude of the numbers, or linear with the size (length) of the numbers.

For a 32-bit computer, numbers up to 2^32 will take 1 unit of time to add, numbers up to 2^64 will take 2 units, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question you have roughly 100*100*100 combinations for the first set (let's ignore that addition is commutative).  For the next set you have 100*200*200, and for the third you have 100*300*300.  So it looks like you have an O(n^2) process going on there.  So if you want to calculate twice as many sets, it will take you four times as long.  If you want to calculate thrice as many, it's going to take nine times as long.  This is not exponential (such as 2^n), but usually referred to as quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how long "and so on" lasts. As long as you maximum number, cubed, fits in your longest integer type, no.  It always takes just one instruction to add, so it's constant time.

Now, if you assume an arbitrary precision machine, like say writing these numbers on the tape of a turing machine in decimal symbols, then adding will take a longer time.  In that case, consider how long it would take?  In other words, think about how the length of a string of decimal symbols grows to represent a number *n*.  It will take time at least proportional to that length.

Comment: So, if the set of numbers were to go on towards say, 80 digits long, than the amount of time taken to add 3 would take the same amount of CPU time? And you didn't really answer my other question, if the time taken for each new set of numbers will increase at a constant exponential rate.